# Multilingual SVG for the web

Tags: website-design, inkscape, svg

Is there a way to create multilingual SVG files for the web?

I have an SVG with text that I use on a website.

Now if the user changes the language on the website I should normally create a new images for that language. Is there a way to add translation strings to an SVG that change based on some parameter?

Comment: I'm very interested in the solution too, but only, if it can be put into one SVG file. I'm not used to work with javascript, browser detection and xml-nodes, but I guess it should be possible to hide a node by name, or set its transparency to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use jQuery to detect what language the browser is and use separate files, such as:

```
icon_de.svg
icon_en.svg
icon_se_svg
```

Then with jQuery use `navigator.language` to detect the language and if you have that SVG set then append to `icon_.svg`.

Example for `navigator.language`:

```
if (window.navigator.language != "en") {       
  doLangSelect(window.navigator.language); 
}
```

Research:

- [NavigatorLanguage.language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language)
- [Insert “t” into an images path using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949724/insert-t-into-an-images-path-using-jquery)
- [JavaScript for detecting browser language preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)
- [jQuery browser language detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317335/jquery-browser-language-detection)
- [Language Codes](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm)

Comment: Content negotiation - if the web server supports this - should do the trick without any client-side scripting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation

Comment: You say use jQuery but your code given doesn't use jQuery... There's no need for jQuery for this type of thing (or much of one in general these days)

Comment: I'm looking for a single file solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Support for this in SVG renderers is not universal, so don't rely on it, but where it works it works:

```xml
<switch>
  <text systemLanguage="de">Das ist der übersetzte Text auf Deutsch</text>
  <text>This is the default text in English</text>
</switch>
```

- [MDN for `<switch/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/switch)
- [MDN for `systemLanguage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/systemLanguage)

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!